# Unusual HTML Audio race condition

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am trying to record audio clips and create an object URL for playback. I want this to happen as soon as the page is loaded, however there appears to be a race condition. The blob is always created and full of data, but sometimes the `audioURL` is playable, sometimes it is not. Why does this race condition exist?

```
const MicRecorder = require("mic-recorder-to-mp3");
this.recorder = new MicRecorder({
  bitRate: 128,
});
this.recorder.start();
// wait for some button press.

this.recorder
    .stop()
    .getMp3()
    .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
      this.buffer = buffer;
      this.blob = blob;
      console.log(blob.arrayBuffer()); // The blob always prints and is full of data.

      // Create Audio for playing
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);
      console.log(audioUrl); // This audio Url is sometimes playable, sometimes not
      this.audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
...

// Some button is clicked.
this.audio.play();
```

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.`

If you load `audioURL` sometimes you can play the audio clip:
[image]

And sometimes you can't, and there appears to be no data:
[image]

Comment: `then(` is async and `console.log(audioUrl)` wont play a file. show where are you adding audioUrl onto the media element

Comment: I know it won't play a file, but it will print a URL which I can load in another tab (which I have included screenshots of). I have debugged my way to this point. The actual error is when I try to: `this.audio = new Audio(audioUrl); this.audio.play();` complains `DOMException: The element has no supported sources.`